# Why 'A left join B' and 'B right join A' are different in Clickhouse?

Tags: sql, grammar, clickhouse

I don't care the order of the query result. From relational algebra point of view, these should be the same. The two queries give different results in Clickhouse.

Querys:

```
select count(*) from A left join B on A.product_id = B.product_id and A.date = B.date
```

got 20000 rows;

```
select count(*) from B right join A on A.product_id = B.product_id and A.date = B.date
```

gives 300000 rows instead.

Comment: Adding sample data to your question would not only help us, it might also explain your current observations.

Comment: Logically they should produce the same result, so something else is happening here. Please try to reduce some sample data to a [mcve].

Comment: It will produce different results if one table is distributed and another is not.